# Validating a date field in a sub-form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a main form that includes a number of sub-forms. One of the sub-forms contains a pair of date fields for entering a date range. I have created the entity classes and the form classes, and have updated services.yml appropriately.

The form renders fine. The problem is that the date fields are not being validated when the form is submitted. I can leave them blank or put anything in them that I like and I never get a validation error. I've tested validation of a date field in the top-level form and it worked as expected.

For testing I created a simple form and sub-form. The main test form has two fields: a text field and a sub-form field. The sub-form has two fields, a date field and a check box field.

As for the real case, I've created the entity and form classes and updated services.yml.  The form displays fine. The date field fails to generate any errors when the form is submitted with an invalid date.

I have tried specifying validation with annotations in the entity classes, a constraints attribute in the $builder->add() method call, and both at the same time ;-)

The current add() call for the date field looks like this:

```
    ...
      ->add( 'date',
             'date',
             [
               'attr'            => [ 'placeholder' => 'a date (mm/dd/yyyy)' ],
               'error_bubbling'  => true,
               'format'          => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
               'html5'           => false,
               'input'           => 'datetime',
               'invalid_message' => 'Invalid date (use mm/dd/yyyy)',
               'label'           => false,
               'widget'          => 'single_text',
               'constraints'     =>
                 [
                   new NotBlank(),
                   new Type( '\DateTime' )
                 ]
             ] )
    ...
```

Suggestions?

Environment:
- PHP V5.5.9
- Symfony V2.7.4
- Twig V1.21.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding a Valid() constraint to the sub-form field in the main form, it comes down to the error_bubbling attributes.

The fields in the sub-form need to be set error_bubbling true to move any errors up to the sub-form field in the main form.

The sub-form field in the main form needs to set error_bubbling false to associate any sub-form errors with the sub-form field.

Through the use of a debugger and judicious {{ dump() }} tags, I finally realized that the sub-form errors were being added to the main form's global collection of errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `SubFormType` to `MainForm` do the following to validate sub forms:

```
$builder->add('sub_form', new SubFormType, array(
         'constraints' => array(
          new Valid()
         ));
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Amin, I added the constraint to the sub-form field definition in the main form. No Joy. Should have remembered that one myself. Had to do that for other projects to get any sub-form fields validated. Date fields are the only ones I've had this problem with.